# two div shrinking and and other div gowing as we scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple divs to display. But Three should be displayed at a time on the screen. The `active_div` should be somewhat large and other two should be be smaller but of same size. I'm able to do this. But I need to add a effect such that as soon as the `active_div` is scrolled, it starts shrinking and the next div which is going to be next `active_div` starts growing till it comes to middle of the screen and start shrinking again. I've used transition effects but it is not working properly. I need other solution based on JS maybe.

```
      <div class="col-9">
        <div class="item">  <!-- smaller in size -->
          lorem iosum
        </div>

        <div class="item_active"> <!-- Bigger in size -->
          lorem iosum
        </div>

        <div class="item">  <!-- smaller in size -->
        lorem iosum
        </div>

        <div class="item">
         lorem iosum
        </div>

        <div class="item">
         lorem iosum
        </div>

        <div class="item">
         lorem iosum
        </div>

        <div class="item">
         lorem iosum
        </div>
   </div>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
var listItem = $(".item");
let currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
$(".item").removeClass("item__active");

for (let i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
  if (currentScroll < listItem[i].offsetTop) {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 90) {
      i=listItem.length-1;
    }

    listItem[i].classList.add("item__active");
    listItem[i].style.transform ='scale(1)';
    listItem[i].style = 'transition-duration: 0.7s';
    let j=1;
    while (j<7){
      if (i-j>=0)
      {
        listItem[i-j].style.transform ='scale('+(1-j*0.1)+')';
        listItem[i].style = 'transition-duration: 0.7s';
      }
      if (i+j<listItem.length)
      {
        listItem[i+j].style.transform ='scale('+(1-j*0.1)+')';
        listItem[i].style = 'transition-duration: 0.7s';
      }
      ++j;
    }
    break;
  }
}


$(window).scroll(function() {
let currentScroll = window.pageYOffset - 5;
$(".item").removeClass("item__active");
for (let i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
  if (currentScroll < listItem[i].offsetTop) {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
      i=listItem.length-1;
    }
    listItem[i].classList.add("item__active");
    listItem[i].style.transform ='scale(1)';
    listItem[i].style = 'transition-duration: 0.7s';
    let j=1;
    while (j<7){
      if (i-j>=0)
      {
        listItem[i-j].style.transform ='scale('+(1-j*0.1)+')';
        listItem[i].style = 'transition-duration: 0.7s';
      }

      if (i+j<listItem.length)
      {
        listItem[i+j].style.transform ='scale('+(1-j*0.1)+')';
        listItem[i].style = 'transition-duration: 0.7s';
      }

      ++j;
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

});`

CSS:

```
    .item_active{
width:auto;
}

.item{
width: 990px;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question and include your `CSS` without it Me/others cannot tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: Added CSS and JS code.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the below link:
https://scrollmagic.io/

It may be useful for you.
And here is an example link: 
https://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_tweening.html